# ng-model set date in form

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i want to set a date in `ng-model`.

this works fine:

```
<input type="date" class="form-control" ng-model="myDate.value" placeholder="yyyy-MM-dd"  />
```

controller:

```
$scope.myDate = {
     value: new Date(2015, 9, 22)
 };
```

**But i want this to work**

```
$scope.myFormObj.myDate = {
     value: new Date(2015, 9, 22)
 };

<input type="date" class="form-control" ng-model="myFormObj.myDate.value" placeholder="yyyy-MM-dd"  />
```

The `ng-model` is in this case **myFormObj.myDate**

I need this syntax because after submit i save all data in `myFormObj-json` object like `myFormObj`.name and so on.

i get the error:

```
 Cannot set property 'myDate' of undefined
```

Comment: Have you defined `$scope.myFormObj` as `{}`

Comment: yes in the service i set it as {}

Comment: @MinasMinas U cannot access then `$scope` of the controller inside a service!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$scope.myDate = {
     value: new Date(2015, 9, 22)
 };
```

In above code `myDate` is object created by `{}` but in `$scope.myFormObj.myDate`, you have created object of `myDate` using `{}` but `myFormObj` is **not defined yet**. So first defined it and then set `myDate`.

So your code looks like:

```
$scope.myFormObj = {};
$scope.myFormObj.myDate = {
     value: new Date(2015, 9, 22)
 };
```